# How to rotate pseudo SVG chevron element on click

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to figure out how to rotate an SVG chevron down arrow on click with CSS only so that it rotates 180 degrees and points upward on click. Then when clicked again, it points down again. This is necessary because I've run into an issue where my Rich Text Editor is converting a lot of my markup, such as `<i>` to `<e>`.

Here's what I have so far:

**HTML**

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center"">
      <div class="smb-chevron-container">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#view-more">
          View all
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="collapse" id="view-more">
  <div class="smb-card-deck collapse">
    More content goes here...
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.smb-card-deck {
  display: flex;
  flex: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 10px;
}

a.accordion-toggle::after {
    content: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg width="1.2em" height="1.2em" fill="%230568ae" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"></path></svg>');
    vertical-align: -0.3em;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] .rotate {
   -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
   transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
   -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
   transform: rotate(180deg);
}
a[data-toggle="collapse"].collapsed .rotate {
   -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
   transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/Codewalker/pen/PoWeXBP

Comment: You can't manipulate the attributes of an element with CSS alone, only it's state (`:hover, :active, :focus,` etc.). You could rotate it in the `:active` state, but as soon as you click anywhere else, it will rotate back. You'll have to use JS to give it a class or some other attribute to have it changed permanently (until you change it back).

Comment: @David - I figured out how to embed the SVG, so an answer to the original question is no longer needed since I don't need to use the pseudo approach. I'll now search for a sans-scripting solution for an embedded SVG. Thanks for the post.

Comment: You will need to add `display: inline-block;` to the  `after` and `a.accordion-toggle.collapsed::after {
   transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
   transform: rotate(180deg);
}`

Answer (score 2):

Use a hidden checkbox to trigger transform, so that the icon can be flipped back and forth without JS code.

```css
#checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.accordion-toggle {
  transition: all 0.75s 0.25s;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: rotate(0);
}

#checkbox:checked + .accordion-toggle {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transform-origin: center center;
}
.smb-card-deck {
  display: flex;
  flex: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 10px;
}

a.accordion-toggle {
    content: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg width="1.2em" height="1.2em" fill="%230568ae" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"></path></svg>');
    vertical-align: -0.3em;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center"">
        <div class="smb-chevron-container">
          <label for="checkbox">
            View all
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#view-more">
            </a>
          </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="collapse" id="view-more">
  <div class="smb-card-deck collapse">
    More content goes here...
  </div>
</div>
```